# Case statement to check for algebraic data type

Tags: haskell

The function f1 expects a list of `I` and `S` types from that I created in my algebraic data type.
How do I make my aux function check what is the type of the T instance that I pass into it?

```
data T = I Integer | S String
          deriving Show

f1 xs =
  let aux (y:xs) res = case y of
                            I -> aux xs (res+y)
                            S -> aux xs (res)
                            otherwise -> aux xs (res)
      aux [] res = res
  in aux xs 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You still need to match the *argument* to the data constructor. `I` itself is not a value of type `T`; it's a value of type `Integer -> T`.

```
f1 xs = let aux (y:xs) res = case y of
                                 I value -> aux xs (res + value)
                                 S _ -> aux xs res
            aux [] res = res
        in aux xs 0
```

Likewise, `S` is a value of type `String -> T`. You need to match against the wrapped value as well, but since you won't use it, you can use `_` to tell the compiler that you don't care about the value.

(You can drop the `otherwise`; `I` and `S` exhaustively cover the constructors for `T`.)

---

You can further abstract this by recognizing that you want a fold of `T` that produces an `Integer`. This particular fold, because it will be used with `(+)`, can return the additive identity 0 for any `S` value.

```
foldT :: T -> Integer
foldT (I x) = x
foldT (S _) = 0
```

Then

```
f1 xs = let aux (y:xs) res = aux xs (res + foldT y)
            aux [] res = res
        in aux xs 0
```

which you can write more simply using `sum` and `map`:

```
f1 xs = sum (map foldT xs)
-- f1 = sum . map foldT
```